# Google Cloud Endpoints - Authenticating users from internal database

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

(intro)
I am new to Google Cloud Endpoints and I have started to build some HTTP REST services.
**The purpose of those services is to be consumed directly by the users of my application (Business to Consumer - not business to business).**

(The question)
I need to secure my services in a way to have only registered users being able to retrieve sensible data (and after login). My main purpose is to have the list of registered users saved in my database on CloudSQL (Dont want to use FB of Google Accounts). I was not able to find particular information about this point in the official Google documentation regarding authentication.

Can anyone advise me of the way to proceed and suggest some tutorials?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Endpoints proxy can validate JWTs, and we provide a couple of alternatives for creating those. Both Auth0 and Firebase have good user management capabilities and client-side libraries for generating JWTs. Both allow you to choose an identity provider (like FB or Google) or simply use username/password.

Check out the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users).

If you don't want to use Auth0 or Firebase Authentication, you can sign JWTs yourself with a private key and just give the proxy the URL of the Public Key (see the "Custom" tab on that same documentation page).

As far as looking up individual users in the database, you would have to do that part on your own.

Comment: Thank you @Oaktowner for the help and prompt answer. Maked it as correct answer.